# SQL - insert into from one table to another but manipulate data

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to copy data from one table to another by using the following script:

```
insert into test_report
( company_id
, report_id
, brch_code
, definition
, description
, editable_flag
, executable_flag
, name
, report_type ) 
values
( 2420
, 'RP00002004'
, '0001'
, (select definition from test_template_report where template_id='RP00001242')
, (select description from test_template_report where template_id='RP00001242')
, (select editable_flag from test_template_report where template_id='RP00001242')
, (select executable_flag from test_template_report where template_id='RP00001242')
, (select name from test_template_report where template_id='RP00001242')
, '01' );
```

This is working fine, but the definition field contains XML which would need to be modified slightly.

The following is part of the definition data:

```
<listdef page='25'><reportId>RP00000390</reportId><name>Fund Transfer</name><description>Fund Transfer</description>
```

The `<reportId>RP00000390</reportId>` part would need to be changed to be **RP00002004** as per the **insert into** script.

Like the following:

```
<listdef page='25'><reportId>RP00002004</reportId><name>Fund Transfer</name><description>Fund Transfer</description>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Tag which DMBS you are using, XML manipulation functions vary from one to another.

Comment: So, long story short, it's this bit: `select definition from test_template_report where template_id='RP00001242'`, and you want to replace `RP00000390` with `RP00002004`?

Comment: Yes, so DEFINITION is in XML format and it would only be the <reportId> that would need to be changed.  I've only given one example, but there are many records that need to be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use XMLQuery with a `modify ... replace value of node`:

```
insert into test_report (company_id,report_id,brch_code,definition,description,
  editable_flag,executable_flag,name,report_type)
select 2420, 'RP00002004', '0001',
  XMLQuery('copy $i := $d modify
      (for $j in $i//reportId return replace value of node $j with $r)
      return $i'
    passing definition as "d", 'RP00002004' as "r"
    returning content),
  description, editable_flag, executable_flag, name, '01'
from test_template_report where template_id='RP00001242';
```

You don't need all the individual selects from the template table, a single insert-select will do.

The XML manipulation assumes `definition` is an XMLType; if it isn't you can convert it to one in the `passing` clause, i.e. `passing XMLType(definition) as "d"`. The value of the `reportId` node (or nodes) is replaced with the string passed as `"r"`.

As a quick static demo of that replacement happening, with the XML supplied in-line as a string literal:

```
select
  XMLQuery('copy $i := $d modify
      (for $j in $i//reportId return replace value of node $j with $r)
      return $i'
    passing XMLType(q'[<listdef page='25'><reportId>RP00000390</reportId><name>Fund Transfer</name><description>Fund Transfer</description></listdef>]') as "d",
      'RP00002004' as "r"
    returning content)
  as modified_definition
from dual;

MODIFIED_DEFINITION                                                                                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<listdef page="25"><reportId>RP00002004</reportId><name>Fund Transfer</name><description>Fund Transfer</description></listdef>
```

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adxdb/query-and-update-XML.html#GUID-9DE1EAEA-60A6-47AF-B4CC-28AB2BC5C998).

Answer (score 0):

The [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REPLACE.html) function replaces one text string with another, so you could change

```
definition
```

to

```
replace(definition, '<reportId>RP00000390</reportId>', '<reportId>RP00002004</reportId>')
```

You can also get all the columns you need from `test_template_report` in one go:

```
insert into test_report
     ( company_id
     , report_id
     , brch_code
     , definition
     , description
     , editable_flag
     , executable_flag
     , name
     , report_type )
select 2420
     , 'RP00002004'
     , '0001'
     , replace(tr.definition, '<reportId>RP00000390</reportId>', '<reportId>RP00002004</reportId>')
     , tr.description
     , tr.editable_flag
     , tr.executable_flag
     , tr.name
     , '01'
from   test_template_report tr
where  tr.template_id = 'RP00001242';
```

If you wanted to replace any value of `reportIf` and not just `'RP00000390'`, you could use `regexp_replace`:

```
insert into test_report
     ( company_id
     , report_id
     , brch_code
     , definition
     , description
     , editable_flag
     , executable_flag
     , name
     , report_type )
select 2420
     , 'RP00002004'
     , '0001'
     , regexp_replace(definition,'<reportId>[^<]+</reportId>','<reportId>RP00002004</reportId>')
     , tr.description
     , tr.editable_flag
     , tr.executable_flag
     , tr.name
     , '01'
from   test_template_report tr
where  tr.template_id = 'RP00001242';
```